# Acceleration due to gravity everwhere on the equator of a spherical ASTEROID of

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, asteroids

[image]

IT IS FROM PRACTICE BOOK OF OLYMPIAD.MY TEACHERS TOLD BUT IT WAS SOME 4 INCH TWO EQUATION AND TOLD ME TO SOLVE.

Comment: Why the caps lock?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the asteroid with an empty cavity. What we have here is two spherical asteroids, one inside the other, and the smaller one with negative mass.

Comment: negative mass in classical mechanics

Comment: Please don't answer homework questions, as they are explicitly off topic and answering them indicates that they are on topic.

Comment: @Aryan Negative mass here is a mathematical trick that results in the same results.. (It doesn't have to exist.)